# CalculateField by dividing with a variable that holds a number

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to calculate a field (using idle python to write my scipt and working with ArcMap 10.3) by dividing two fields then dividing by a variable that holds a number, which the number was calculated by dividing 2 sums.

So essentially I'm trying to divide two ratios but I'm having trouble going about that. Basically the equation is `( a / b ) / ( sum(x) / sum(y))`.

I have the variable set to hold the number of the second ratio of `(sum(x) / sum(y))` but can't figure out how to incorporate the variable into the calculate field expression or how to set up a double division in the expression. As you can see I used TableToNumPyArray to figure out the sum ratio.

```
field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (fc, ["E_Total", "E__Black"], skip_nulls=True)
LQC = 1.0 *(field["E__Black"].sum()) / (field["E_Total"].sum())
#Fields are in long format, 1.0* forces it to be in float format and this section of the code works!



field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (fc, ["E_Total", "E__Black"], skip_nulls=True)
Lratio = 1.0 *(field["E__Black"]) / (field["E_Total"])
expression = '(!'+Lratio+'!/!'+LQC+'!)'
arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "LQ_Black", expression, "PYTHON")
```

Comment: essentially for the fields and the equation it would more be like    ( field A / field B ) / ( sum (field A) / sum (field B)) and I want to populate the new field with the outcome of dividing by both ratios

Comment: Please [post the code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) directly in your question--not as a picture. You'll need to remember to [format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/318935).

Comment: hi, i formatted the code on here the best I can, this is my first time asking a question on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code is doing quite what you think. In `CalculateField_management`, surrounding a name with `!` indicates a field. But as you've set it up here, `Lratio` and `LQC` both are holding float values. So, your expression is going to end up looking like `(!1.0!/!32.6!)`, which is probably not what you want. Since you've already calculated these values, just insert the result of the calculation as the expression, i.e.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "LQ_Black", "{}".format(Lratio / LQC), "PYTHON")
```

If you have a third variable that you want to divide by, for example, `var3`, then

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "LQ_Black", "{}".format(Lratio / LQC / var3), "PYTHON")
```

If you have two fields in `lyr` that you want to divide by the value of `LQC`, you could write your expression as

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "LQ_Black", "!field1! / !field2! / {}".format(LQC), "PYTHON")
```

Comment: How would I have to write it if I wanted the expression to be field/field/LQC? Do i not need anything extra around the variable?

Comment: Edited to address your question

Comment: That worked perfect! Thank you so much for your insight